# Remove gradle nature from eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I just mirrored a repo that uses maven, however when manually editing the maven modules' .project and .classpath files I accidentally used gradle instead of maven. I've since changed the files manually to maven and have gotten rid of all gradle related text I could find, however eclipse is giving me this error on all modules

> Missing Gradle project configuration file:
>   .settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs    EssentialsX     Unknown Gradle
>   Project Configuration Marker

How can I solve this error?

Also, here is this specific maven module's `.project` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Essentials</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

And here is the `.classpath` file

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Files in `.settings` might contain some more references to gradle

Comment: @Kapep
The only two files there do not have any references to gradle as far as I can see.

Comment: Not exactly the best solution thus not marking it the answer, but uninstalling buildship and reinstalling it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8):

To remove a nature from a project go to it's folder and in its `.project` file, under `<natures>` remove `<nature>org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectnature</nature>`.
This will remove the icon (if you had it shown - you can choose to not show an icon even if the nature is applied) and the right click context menu gradle entry.

Also, in the `.classpath` file remove the line `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer"/>`. This exports the entry to the runtime classpath.

You can then delete the build and settings gradle files, the wrapper files if you had them, the .bat file, the `org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs` under `.settings` folder, and the `.externalToolBuilder` if applicable.

Since you already messed with the files and still getting the error I suggest you reapply the gradle nature from Eclipse (use the buildship importer) and when all the errors are resolved do as described above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I had solved this long ago by simply re-installing the gradle plugin for eclipse. You'd think the solution(s) you stated here would work, but for some reason the gradle nature wasn't fully removed, so the re-install of the plugin did the job.